# The fastest way to find dictionary keys that are not exist in another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary A and I want to find `int` keys that are not listed in B in a fast and propper way.

```
Dictionary<int,object> A;

List<int> B;
```

I want get

`A KEYS ARE NOT EXISTING IN B`

Is there a fast and elegant way for that?

Comment: Well keys is a list.. what have you tried?

Comment: What do you want to do with the keys that are not present in B?  Do you output them to the console?

Comment: i got shocked why this question got down vote . i was clear question.

Comment: You can use Linq like `A.Keys.Except(B)`

Comment: @dymanoid please tell us why this question is too board?

Comment: @Martin, measured with BenchmarkDotNet: https://pastebin.com/g7RJQS6d Your solution is slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to use [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8) method from `System.Linq` for that

```cs
var result = A.Keys.Except(B);
```

Comment: B is List<int>?

Comment: Yes, as per your question:)

Comment: i will try it .

Comment: good solution . thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could make a `new HashSet<int> (A.Keys)`, and use the `ExceptWith()` method of the Hashset.

Edit:
since you thought, hashing will break the performance, here is a sample code, which you can drop into linqpad. In most cases, this is still about 30% faster than just using LINQs `.Except()`

```
Dictionary<int, int> A = new Dictionary<int, int>();
List<int> B = new List<int>();

// test filling...
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    int rnd = r.Next(0, 2000000);
    A[rnd] = rnd;

    rnd = r.Next(0, 2000000);
    B.Add(rnd);
}

// Get time for LINQ Except
Stopwatch w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var count = A.Keys.Except(B).Count();
w.Stop();
w.Dump();
count.Dump("Count");

// Get time for Hashset
w = Stopwatch.StartNew();

HashSet<int> ha = new HashSet<int>(A.Keys);
ha.ExceptWith(B);
count = ha.Count;

w.Stop();
w.Dump();
count.Dump("Count");
```

Comment: Hashing makes time over head.

Comment: int.GetHashCode() just returns the int, so the Hashing will be pretty fast.

Comment: good idea and solution .

Comment: @Mr.AF [Except](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,64071682ee3bf309,references) of linq is using an [ExceptIterator](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,e289e6c98881b2b8,references) that uses a set to check values. That's the fastest average way to exclude values. If you're sure that the excluding values list is very small it could be faster to iterate over them - but you need a loop to iterate vs. hashcode calculation.